# Designing SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am creating a Database which should have these datas:

Table Name: PlayerNames

Columns: FirstName, LastName, Rank

Now I have another data which shows the HeadToHead count of winning: For eg.

A-A = Null
A-B = 5 (That means A against B and A won)
A-C = 3 (A against C, and A won)

B-A = 3 (That means B against A, and B won. I dont know A-B and B-A are not same).
B-B = Null
B-C = 4

..... and so on. I have to create a DB for this in which I can pull these records and viewers can select a player and select another player and see their opponent stats. How should DB be designed?

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLAYER
   id, 
   firstname,
   lastname,
   rank,

GAME
   winning_player_id,
   losing_player_id,
   score,

maybe?

Comment: hhmmm...lemme implement this.

Comment: @klm9971 good man if it works please remember to mark as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is another ERM:
It seems to make sense, at least for me. But I think it will be too complicated when you start to write the update/insert queries

[image]